# why this recursion print 0 after some non-zero values?

Tags: c

this is infinite recursion, I am confused why this is printing 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void go(int x)
{
    printf("%d",x);
    go(x+x);
}
int main()
{
    go(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [It didn't print only zero](https://ideone.com/eW4jER)

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior so it could print, or not print, just about anything

Comment: its an infinite recursion. it will crash at some point.

Comment: This is basically an infinite loop, printing non-zero numbers. But since you don't have a newline in your print, they aren't flushed to the console.   The zero is probably the return value from main()

Comment: Printing zeros eventually is completely reasonable even without talking about UB, after all `x` is effectively being shifted left and at some time all the set bits would have been shifted out.

Comment: @harold I understood can you provide some material from where I can study this topic more.

Comment: @Raildex: The compiler may optimize the [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) to a jump that does not use any additional stack space, so the program could run indefinitely without crashing.

Comment: This program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to signed [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). This means that the compiler is allowed to do anything, and you should not expect your program to behave in a certain way.

Comment: @kNIG132103 what do _you_ expect to happen once `x` becomes very large?

Answer (score 2):

The program has undefined behavior, because it will eventually result in signed overflow in `x+x`.

Comment: Yeah, but if it has undefined behavior, then it should print garbage value.

Comment: @kNIG132103 No, _undefined behavior_ means that you do not have any guarantee at all how the program will behave.

Comment: why only zero? not other value

Comment: @kNIG132103 Because the behavior is undefined. Printing only zeros is a valid outcome. Printing random values is also a valid outcome. Not printing anything is also a valid outcome. And so on...

Comment: On this machine this integer overflow lead to `0`. `2^32` can't be represented in `int` or `unsigned int`. On x86 result is zero, but as `user17732522` this is undefined behavior and if compiler discovers this he can discard this code.

Comment: When `unsigned int` would be used then there is no undefined behavior and value is always modulo `2^32` so when this value is reached you have a zero.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/K4671Eea8

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/e475ThnTY

Comment: @MarekR: Correct is not the only criterion for judging an answer, especially “technically correct.” Answers should also be useful. “Undefined behavior” in the sense of the C standard does not mean there is no explanation for the behavior or that nothing can be learned from studying the failure. For example, when a building collapses due to some architectural mistake, we do not just say “The architect failed to conform to requirements, so the building was not defined to stand up.” We study what went wrong and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an integer to itself repeatedly, you will eventually reach a point where an integer datatype is too small to hold the result of the multiplication.  This will eventually result in a zero (or undefined, see below) value.

Adding an integer to itself, is the same as **multiplying by two.** If your datatype is *signed* the behaviour of the resulting overflow is undefined.  If the dataype is *unsigned* you will eventually reach a zero value.

Comment: The lack of a newline would explain why no output is seen immediately. It does not, by itself, explain why no output other than “0” is seen, as output buffers are flushed at normal program termination and when they are full.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP has changed the problem description (title) so I updated my answer too...

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior (UB) because of the eventual integer overflow. So there are no guarantees of any form of output or behavior.

One explanation for why it prints zeroes as one possible outcome of overflow UB, is that on a 32 bit system it will overflow at the point of `1073741824 + 1073741824`. This equals 2^31 but `INT_MAX` will be 2^31 - 1, hence the overflow. A common behavior when that overflow happens is to switch to the binary representation of the number 2^31, which in 2's complement will be `-2147483648`.

And then in the next step `-2147483648 + -2147483648` ends up as zero. This isn't particularly logical (it's UB), I guess you can think of it as `-2147483648 + -2147483648` = `-4294967296`, this being equivalent to binary representation `0xFFFFFFFF00000000`. Truncate that down to 4 bytes and you get zero.

The reason why I keep mentioning binary representation is that integer overflow is very likely well-defined behavior in the actual CPU. It will just wrap-around as an unsigned number will, discard anything that won't fit and set an overflow flag.

And from there you'll have endless `0 + 0`, unless the recursion wasn't optimized but crashes in a stack overflow.